# How to call rest api in parse.com using cloud function with xml parameter

Tags: parse-platform

i want to integrate payment gateway authentication with parse and need to save token on parse so how to call rest curl in cloud code with XML parameter?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself.?

Answer (score 0):

Parse includes a Stripe module in cloud code for [processing credit cards](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-modules-stripe) which may be of interest to you.

You can also access external APIs through cloud code using [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced). You can specify parameters using JSON or a raw string.